# How to find a specific link from an href using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first experience with JS, so please forgive the noob question.
I'm trying to make a userscript for a phpBB forum that'll allow me to automatically bookmark every topic I create.

My approach is to add an onclick listener to the submit button.
I'll use the code found in another question:

```
    var submit = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    submit.onclick = function() {
        ;
    }
```

Before that though I want to find a link to bookmarking the topic in one of the hrefs on the page and store it as a variable.

I know that it will always take the form of

```
<a href="./viewtopic.php?f=FORUM_NUMBER&amp;t=TOPIC_NUMBER&amp;bookmark=1&amp;hash=HASH"
```

The final code should look something like (hopefully it's the correct form)

```
var link = THE LINK EXTRACTED FROM THE MATCHED HREF
var submit = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
submit.onclick = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'link'; }, 1000);
}
```

My issue is I don't know how to approach locating the href that I need and getting the link from it. Haven't found any similar questions about this.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Give the link a class use [`getElementByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); // get all <a> tags
var link = '';
if (anchors) {
  // getAttribute(attributeName) gets the value of attributeName (in your case, the value of 'href' attribute
  // .map(), .find() and .filter() are available methods for arrays in JS
  // .startsWith() is an available method for matching strings in JS.
  // You can even experiment with other regex-based string matching methods like .match()

  // Use one of the following lines, based on what you require:

  // to get the first matching href value
  link = anchors.map(anchor => anchor.getAttribute('href')).find(url => url.startsWith('./viewtopic.php')); // or provide a better regex pattern using .match()

  // to get all matching href values as an array
  link = anchors.map(anchor => anchor.getAttribute('href')).filter(url => url.startsWith('./viewtopic.php')); // or provide a better regex pattern using .match()
}
```

Since you're not new to coding, check out [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) if you're new to JS :)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `document.getElementsByTagName("a")`; which returns a collection of all the `<a></a>` loaded in the dom.
Then you can find it in the list and and use .href to get it's href attribute.